# How do you know when two objects can communicate?

Tags: python, class, object

```
class GuiMaker(Frame):
    #more code
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)        # make frame stretchable
        self.start()                            # for subclass: set menu/toolBar
        self.makeMenuBar()                      # done here: build menu-bar
        self.makeToolBar()                      # done here: build tool-bar
        self.makeWidgets()                      # for subclass: add middle part
    #more code

class TextEditor:
    #more code
    def start(self):
    #more code
```

How come self.start() will call TextEditor's start if self refers to GuiMaker or else how come self refers to TextEditor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `GuiMaker` inherit from `TextEditor` somewhere?  In other words is Frame a descendant of `TextEditor`?  That would cause `TextEditor`'s start method to be called.

Other than that, I don't see any way for the code (as written) to have `GuiMaker.start` call `TextEditor.start`

Comment: You can always use print statements or pdb breakpoints to see what is actually being called.